# cp does not seem to use copy on write on btrfs by default

Tags: filesystem, btrfs

I'm running a rather default Kubuntu 16.10 setup with btrfs. To my dismay and surprise I found that copying files is not instant as I would expect with btrfs.

I need to manually force copy-on-write via `cp --reflink` for this to work. Why is this the case and how can I correct this behavior?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80351/why-is-cp-reflink-auto-not-the-default-behaviour

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal behavior. If you use `mv`, it will do it instantly. If you copy, it is supposed to be a "real" copy.

Comment: why would that be normal on a copy on write FS? Any copy on a copy on write FS should typically be near instant?

Comment: Ah, I just saw you actual answer was given as comment to my post. Thanks, the mentioned link https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80351/why-is-cp-reflink-auto-not-the-default-behaviour explains what's going on

Comment: Giving this more though though, I still wonder: I don't want any copy operation on my FS ever to do anything but copy on write, never mind if it was triggered by cp, or file manager or by a software ... any way to achieve this?

Comment: @Nik use an alias like an answer on your linked question?